# I made a React hook to control visibility of NavBar depending on scroll position, scroll direction, and scroll speed. How can I optimize this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the React hook. I wanted to emulate the behavior on this site: [Humboldt forum](https://www.humboldtforum.org/)

Basically, navbar is sticky, hides when you scroll down, reappears when you scroll up quickly, is always visible on the top.

```html
const useScrollSpeed = (navHeight: number, maxScrollSpeed: number) => {

  const [lastScrollTime, setLastScrollTime] = useState(new Date().getTime());
  const [currentScrollPos, setCurrentScrollPos] = useState(0)
  const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = useState(0);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const distance = Math.abs(currentScrollPos - prevScrollPos);
    const scrollSpeed = distance / (new Date().getTime() - lastScrollTime);

  
      if (currentScrollPos > prevScrollPos) {
        setVisible(false);
      } else {
        if (scrollSpeed > maxScrollSpeed) {
          setVisible(true);
        }
      }

    setPrevScrollPos(currentScrollPos);
    setLastScrollTime(new Date().getTime());
  };

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    useEffect(() => {
      setCurrentScrollPos(window.scrollY)
  
      if (currentScrollPos < navHeight) {
        setVisible(true);
      } 
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, [window.scrollY]);
  }
  

  return visible;
};
export default useScrollSpeed;
```

How can I optimize this further for performance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my improved es-linted version:

```js
const useScrollSpeed = (navHeight: number, maxScrollSpeed: number) => {

  const [lastScrollTime, setLastScrollTime] = useState(new Date().getTime());
  const [currentScrollPos, setCurrentScrollPos] = useState(0)
  const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = useState(0);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    const distance = Math.abs(currentScrollPos - prevScrollPos);
    const scrollSpeed = distance / (new Date().getTime() - lastScrollTime);

  
      if (currentScrollPos > prevScrollPos) {
        setVisible(false);
      } else {
        if (scrollSpeed > maxScrollSpeed) {
          setVisible(true);
        }
      }

    setPrevScrollPos(currentScrollPos);
    setLastScrollTime(new Date().getTime());
  }, [currentScrollPos, prevScrollPos, lastScrollTime, setVisible, maxScrollSpeed])


  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentScrollPos(window.scrollY)

    if (currentScrollPos < navHeight) {
      setVisible(true);
    } 
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [currentScrollPos, handleScroll, navHeight]);

  

  return visible;
};
export default useScrollSpeed;
```